# Prove that the limit of a sequence of conformal mappings is also conformal

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the open unit disc in the complex plane, and let $\{D_n\}$ be a descending sequence of simply connected domains in $\mathbb{D}$, i.e. $D_{n+1}\subset D_{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Assume that $D=\text{Int}(\bigcap_{n}D_n)$ is non-empty, and $0\in D$.

For every $n\geq 1$, let $g_n:\mathbb{D}\to D_n$ be a conformal mapping such that $g_n(0)=0$, and assume that the sequence $\{g_n \}$ converges normally on $\mathbb{D}$ to an analytic function $g$.

What I would like to show is that $g$ is a conformal mapping from $\mathbb{D}$ to $D$.

By invoking Hurwitz's Theorem, we know that $g$ is either univalent or constant, so as long as we can prove that $g$ is non-constant, we know that it's a conformal mapping onto $g(\mathbb{D})$. However neither do I know how to show that $g$ is non-constant, nor do I know how to show that its image is exactly equal to $D$ (provided that it's non-constant). Again, by Hurwitz's Theorem, I can manage to show that $g(\mathbb{D})\subset D$ if it's non-constant. However I don't know how to show the other direction of inclusion.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $c>0, D_c(0) \subset D \subset D_n$. Hence $g_n^{-1}(z)$ maps $D_c(0) \to \mathbb D=D_1(0)$ or $g_n^{-1}(cz)$ maps the unit disc to itself and preserves zero, so by Schwarz Lemma its derivative at $0$ is at most $1$ in absolute value; but this means $|g_n^{-1}(0)'| \le 1/c$ or $|g_n'(0)| \ge c$ hence $|g'(0)| \ge c>0$ so $g$ is non-constant

Let $G=g(\mathbb D) \subset D \subset D_n$ open because $g$ is holomorphic nonconstant; considering the restrictions of $g_n^{-1}$ to $G$ they form a normal family being uniformly bounded and we will show that any limit point of it is $g^{-1}$ which imnplies that $g_n^{-1} \to g^{-1}$ normally on $G$; note first that if $g_{n_k}^{-1} \to h$ we have that $|g_{n_k}^{-1}(0)'|=|1/g'_{n_k}(0)| \to |1/g'(0)| >0$ by the above, hence $h$ is not constant so it is univalent.

Fix $w \in \mathbb D$; if $\epsilon >0$ $g_n(z)-g(w)$ has a zero $|z_n-w| <\epsilon/2$ for large enough $n$ hence $g_{n_k}(z_{n_k})=g(w)$ for $n_k$ large enough, or $g_{n_k}^{-1}(g(w))=z_{n_k}$ while also $|h(g(w))-g_{n_k}^{-1}(g(w))| < \epsilon/2$ again for large enough $k$ by the defintion of $h$. Remembering that $|z_{n_k}-w| <\epsilon/2$ also, by the triangle inequality we get that $|h(g(w))-w| < \epsilon$ hence $h(g(w))=w$ for all $w \in \mathbb D$ and the above claim has been proved.

But now this means that $h=g^{-1}$ is a univalent function mapping $G$ onto $\mathbb D$ and of course if $G \ne D$ we can get a subsequence of $g_n^{-1}$ normally convergent to some $h_1$ on $D$; by definition $h=h_1$ on $G$, hence $h_1$ is also univalent by Hurwitz as it is nonconstant and $h_1(D) \subset \mathbb D$ which is a contradiction since the restriction of $h_1$ to $G$ already covers the whole $\mathbb D$ so $h_1$ cannot be univalent. This means $G=D$ and we are done!